# Should I use "her" or "herself" in the following examples?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> She shared snippets of her/herself with him.
>
> He was doing fine, even better than her/herself.

Should I choose "her" or "herself"? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She shared snippets of **herself** with him.

Using ***her*** would indicate ambiguity, as if "she" is sharing the photos/snippets of "some other girl" with "him". To avoid such misunderstandings or ambiguity, it is better to use *herself*.

In case, you want to picture the fact, that "*she*" is sharing the photos/snippets of "*some other girl*", then you must use ***her***.

---

> He was doing fine, even better than **her**.

This sentence certainly portrays third person part of view. Hence it would mean the usage of ***her***. This is like a comparison statement made to compare their physical health/mental health/social interactivity, etc.